# MySQL: how to create table with multidimentional integer array?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a table with multidimentional integer array,
I tried this syntax, but it didn't work for me unfortuantly:

```
create table testarray(testarr INT(20)(10));
```

so what to do in this case? thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by storing trying to store an array in a relational field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You could do something like convert your array to a comma-separated string, and store this. Use `serialize` function and store it into the `varchar` field

Answer (score 0):

No. But you could create a test array table and link to it.

```
CREATE TABLE testarray(ID NT, RowId INT, Element_0 INT, Element_1 INT..Element_9 INT);
```

Not you reference the array with testarray.ID as a foreign key from wherever you wanted to have the array original.

That's arguable better then using a comma-separated.

Or stick a json syntax array in a varchar field.